# loosing data on page refresh php session

Tags: php, session, post

I am posting data from one site to another, then turning that posted data into a session.

**form from other site**

```
<form action="https://www.122.co.uk/11/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1010101">
<input type="submit" value="Go" style="font-size:14px; padding:20px;">
```

I then post this data to my new site where I turn it into a variable `$userid`

then checking that the variable is empty or not, if not show some code.

**check variable is not empty**

```
if (!empty($userid)) {
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "You Are Logged In,</br>";
        echo "Your User ID is <strong>" . $_POST['userid'] . "</strong>.";
```

When I refresh the page with a button click I loose the session data, so the code in the check dose not show.

how do I have a button to refresh to page and keep session data ?

**button to refresh**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary hidebutton showbuttonv2" role="button" id="homebutton" onClick="history.go(0)">Home</button>
```

**Full code spinet**

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];

//$_SESSION["userID"] = $userid;

if (!empty($userid)) {
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "You Are Logged In,</br>";
        echo "Your User ID is <strong>" . $_POST['userid'] . "</strong>.";
```

Comment: The session is site specific! Do you mean from site 1 you cannot see the session you created on site 2?

Comment: you do not check if your $_POST Variables are empty, a refresh does indeed normally empty the post variables ( some ask you if you wish do resend ). It's not good design, but for your purpose you could try to check if(!empty($_POST[...]) $userid = $_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, I am sending data from one site, then turning my POST data into a session with start session

Comment: @Najzero the main problem setting the session so i do not loose the session

Comment: You dont show us any HTML that supports the existance of a `<form>` or an `<input....>` with the attribute `name="userid"` **Add more of the relevant code please**

Comment: @RiggsFolly no problem will update question

Comment: you are overwriting your session everytime you enter the page. Check if your $_SESSION['userid'] is not set and if there is a $_POST request and then declare it to $_SESSION['userid']

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani thank you this information is helpful, ill look into this.

Comment: How do you launch the page initially? Do you use `http` the first time?

Comment: yes i do, ive updated the question to show the post

Comment: A "little" heads up: Everything you send to the client, and expect to get sent back can be falsified by the user. And I mean _everything_! In this case it would be trivial for anyone to change the user ID, using any browser, to log in as the admin-user instead. Or any other user, for that matter. This is why you always use username and passwords, or a third party solution like OAuth, OpenID etc for authentication between different servers/sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're always overwriting the session data with the POST data, even if there isn't anything in the `$_POST['userid']` field.

I see that you are very new to programming (PHP), and as such I would recommend you to sit down and think a bit about what you want to do. Then try to write down short item lists of the steps needed to do these things. Remember to be *really* specific, as that is what you need to be when writing the code. This is called pseudo-code, and is a vital tool in programming.
Once you've done that, read through the code you've written, and really read what it does. Not just what you expect it to. Then you'll learn a lot about how programming works. ;)

Short example, based upon the code you've posted:

- Start session.
- If user submitted ID -> Store ID in session
- If session contains user ID -> Show login confirmation.
  : Else -> Show login form

Your code, in "English" form.

```
// Start the session
session_start ();

// Save the POSTed value from the form in the session array.
$_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid']; 

// Save the POSTed value fromthe form in the session array, and a variable of its own.
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];


// If we have a (non-empty) value in the user ID variable.
if (!empty ($userid)) {
    // Show the login confirmation.
}
```

As you can see, there is a discrepancy between your expected behavior and the code you wrote. :)

Remember: Details *always* matter in programming.

Also, using JavaScript's `history` to create breadcrumb isn't the best option. This will lead to somewhat unpredictable behavior for the users, especially if they come to your page from a web search. (It'll take them to the search engine again, instead of your home page.)
That is why I recommend using proper URLs instead. Either relative, or dynamically created full ones. That way you always have full control where the user ends up when clicking on your links. :)

**Edit, Added #2:**
Here's how I'd write the code, to perform the tasks outlined by the pseudo-code.

```
// Using sessions to persist data across page views.
session_start ();

// Check if user has tried to log in.
if ($user = login_user ($username, $password)) {
    // He has. Use session to keep him logged in.
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
}

// If the user is logged in, show confirmation message.
if (!empty ($_SESSION['user']['id'])) {
    $page = 'login_confirmed';
} else {
    $page = 'login_form';
}
```

See how the comments, and the code, aligns withe the pseudo-code from the bullet list? And how it describes exactly what you want, in detail? ;)

Comment: hi, thanks for the insightful information, the main question is when i refresh the page why do i loose the session variable ?

Comment: good clean code with good comments, however when i click my button i loose the variable value

Comment: @BenjaminOats I haven't changed your code, I've merely commented on exactly what it does. I've left it up to you, as a learning experience, to find out why and how to fix it. A big hint as to what's wrong, is the discrepancy between the exact wording used in the bullet list, vs the wording used in the comments. This is a hurdle all new (and old) programmers must overcome, and understand, which is why I haven't simply changed it for you. ;) I'll add an example of how I'd do it though.

Comment: Yep the reason i accepted your answer is because your exploitation helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @BenjaminOats That is good to know! Glad I could be of help, and good luck forward with your programming. :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want to set `$_SESSION['userid']` to the value of `$_POST['userid']`  if this last one is empty.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    // check that $_POST['userid'] is set
    if (isset($_POST['userid'])) {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }

    if (!empty($userid)) {
?>
```

Comment: Your edit is correct, but I think the answer would be a lot better if you cleaned up the unnecessary code as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I shortened a bit the code snippet.

Comment: if my page reloaded with the button, how could i keep the current session